# Using callbacks inside a function callback

Tags: python, callback, arguments

Given the following three functions:

```
def return_arg( *arg ):
    return arg[0]

def an_expression( x, y, **kwargs ):
    return x*x + y*y

def sub_function( x, y, F ): 
       return x + y + F(**locals())
```

I can call the following `sub_function( 1, 2, an_expression )` to obtain `8`.

I can also call:

```
T = 5
return_arg(T)
```

How can I call

```
sub_function( 1, 2, return_arg)
```

in the case that I want to have `return_arg(T)`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect ? maybe aprecise example of the behavior wanted.

Comment: It's not obvious what you want to do with `**locals()`.  Are you trying to do something like collecting the locals from the calling scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to pass args and/or kwargs to your callback evaluator

```
def sub_function( x, y, F, *args, **kwargs): 
       return x + y + F(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can call it however you want, e.g.,

```
sub_function( 1, 2, return_arg, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood fully your question, but I think what you need is [partial function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
my_partial = partial(return_arg, T)
sub_function( 1, 2, my_partial)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this works great! I decided to go with RishiG's answer, as it doesn't import another library. :)

Comment: It's in the Python standard library! ;)